# Difficulties to set outlines of an ImageView using a drawabale ressource file

Tags: android, kotlin, imageview

I want to set a background on my imageView  corner-rounded outlines using a drawable resource file . But when i set it ? i can't even see the outline . Seems that the image is hidding the background , how could i figure it out ? Here is my drawable resource file content media_contour_background.xml :

> 

```
<corners android:radius="@dimen/_50sdp" />

<stroke
    android:width="@dimen/_10sdp"
    android:color="@color/lagfo_color"
    android:dashWidth="@dimen/_10sdp"
    />
```

and here is how i set the background :

> ```
>        binding.photo.setImageResource(R.drawable.media_contour_background)
> ```

Comment: Of course an image goes on top of the background.  You'd only see the background if the image is translucent, or the image does not fill the view

Comment: How could i rearrange it then ?

Comment: If it's a constant image, I'd put the border into the image and not use a background

Comment: No , it is not a constant image

Comment: I had used ShapeableImageView and i  managed to set outlines but the problems was i couldn't make the corners rounded .